# 検索オプションの詳細が翻訳できない

Tags: バグ, 機能の要求, 翻訳

検索にオプションを付けた際に英語だと "Search options **questions only**" のように表示されますが、このオプション部分 "questions only" に該当する string が Transifex に登録されておらず、翻訳できませんでした。翻訳できるようにしていただきたいです。

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/3509 が使われている例

> [image]

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/11204 が使われている例

> [image]

※ MSE に同様の報告が無いようだったので、MSE にも[投稿しました](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348067/341401)。